# Python ternary operation on vectors

Tags: python, vector, ternary

Could someone help me with the proper format of a python ternary operation on a vector? I have two dataframes temperature: `df_today` and `df_yesterday`. I am trying to calculate a new column for `df_today` to determine whether the temperature is warmer than yesterday:

`df["warmer_than_yesterday"] = 'yes, warmer' if df["temp_celsius"] > df_yesterday["temp_celsius"] and df["temp_celsius"] > 10 else 'nah, not warmer'`

However, I keep getting the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can combine your if conditions into one, using `np.maximum` (for conciseness). Should also be more performant.

```
m = df["temp_celsius"] > np.maximum(10, df_yesterday["temp_celsius"])
```

Now, pass this mask to `np.where`,

```
df["warmer_than_yesterday"] = np.where(m, 'yes', 'no')
```

Or, to `loc` to set slices:

```
df["warmer_than_yesterday"] = 'no'
df.loc[m, "warmer_than_yesterday"] = 'yes'
```